# ES6+ / React Native class properties: The first one is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, class-properties

I'm trying to use the panResonder in my React Native app. I tried doing so using class properties instead of constructor and `super()`. Here is the code:

```
export default class Deck extends Component {
  panResponder = PanResonder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
    onPanResponderMove: (event, gesture) => {},
    onPanResponderRelease: () => {}
  });
  state = { panResponder };

  renderCards = () => this.props.data.map(item => this.props.renderCard(item));

  render() {
    return <View>{this.renderCards()}</View>;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately React is complaining that panResponder is undefined. How is that? Do I have to use a constructor here?

The following code is the only that works for me:

```
export default class Deck extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const panResponder = PanResonder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderMove: (event, gesture) => {},
      onPanResponderRelease: () => {}
    });
    this.state = { panResponder };
  }

  renderCards = () => this.props.data.map(item => this.props.renderCard(item));

  render() {
    return <View>{this.renderCards()}</View>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`panResponder` *property* is defined. `panResponder` *variable* isn't.

`state = { panResponder }` refers to `panResponder` *variable*. Instead, it should be:

```
state = { panResponder: this.panResponder };
```

> Do I have to use a constructor here?

There's no need for explicit `constructor` function here because class fields are parts of it. Function scope allows to define a variable and use object literal shorthand. It doesn't provide real benefits here, but if there's no need for `panResponder` *property*, it could be omitted in favour of a variable:

```
constructor() {
  const panResponder = PanResonder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
    onPanResponderMove: (event, gesture) => {},
    onPanResponderRelease: () => {}
  });

  this.state = { panResponder };
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. I've provided an update regarding variable vs property. If you don't use panResponder property anywhere else, there's no need for it.

Answer (score 2):

use this.panResponder

It'll resolve your issue.

Hope this helps

Comment: `state = { panResponder: this.panResponder };` did it! Thank you very much!